# Button padding only working on default theme

Tags: unity, button

Button padding is working only on default theme! On other themes when the active window is small there is no padding!

YouTube Video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4aY8GyyjuM8

Comment: Does the really have anything to do with Unity? Please log out and try logging in with the Ubuntu Classic mode. If it's still an issue in Classic, it's probably a gtk-window-decorator issue.

Comment: There is no problem in UClassic but It's all fine with emerald theme!

Answer (score 1):

Here lies the answer:

A lot of Ubuntu users requested this guide, because the new Ubuntu 11.10 operating system doesn't provide a tool to add new GTK or icon themes. Why? Because of the GNOME 3 desktop.

How to Install GNOME Themes in Ubuntu 11.10

[Tutorial](http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Install-GNOME-Themes-in-Ubuntu-11-10-231213.shtml)